# How do I set Priority\Pool on an Hadoop Streaming job?

Tags: hadoop

How can I set the Priority\Pool of an Hadoop Streaming job?
It's probably a command-line jobconf parameter (e.g -jobconf something=pool.name) but I haven't been able to find any documentation on this online...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

-jobconf mapred.job.queue.name=<queue_name> mapred.job.priority=<VERY_LOW|LOW|NORMAL|HIGH|VERY_HIGH>

Answer (score 3):

set mapred.job.priority=VERY_HIGH;

option : VERY_LOW|LOW|NORMAL|HIGH|VERY_HIGH

inside Hive CLI